# How to get http error response text in angular 8?

Tags: angular, http

```
this.authservice.login.subscribe(res => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  }, err => {
    this.error = err; // this err returns "Bad request" instead of backend's response text!? 
  }));
```

Can anyone help me? here in err part I didn't get response text from back-end it shows only "Bad Request" every time.

Comment: you are not passing appropriate params for api call resulting in bad request it happens from client side.

Comment: I know why it is bad request. But my question is  How can i get response text in error part ? here i get text but it is "Bad Request" not as back-end sends me like "Invalid Password".

Comment: 400 bad request means server was unable to process your request or you can say it did not hit your api so you can't get your api response.

Comment: Can you confirm with a network trace that the reason phrase is actually sent? Note that the reason phrase does not exist anymore in HTTP/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

export class ErrorHandler {
    public static handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        return throwError(error.error);
    }
}
```

added error handler.